# How can I get the pictures one by one rather than showing them together?

Tags: r, plot, fitdistrplus

When I entered the code `plot(x.logis)`, the output is four pictures showing together, but I am only looking for one of them. How do I plot them separately?

Here is my code:

```
x<-c(2800,3260,66.5,195,420,840,1380,469,260,50,209.8,370,27,420,157)
y<-log10(x)
# load fitdistrplus package for using fitdist function
library(fitdistrplus)
# fit logistic distribution using MLE method
x.logis <- fitdist(y, "logis", method="mle")
plot(x.logis)
```

This is the result of the output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you need is `cdfcomp`, `denscomp`, `ppcomp` and `qqcomp`

```
cdfcomp(x.logis, addlegend=FALSE)
denscomp(x.logis, addlegend=FALSE)
ppcomp(x.logis, addlegend=FALSE)
qqcomp(x.logis, addlegend=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your generous answer. That's exactly what I want